# Cannot install openslide-python on google datalabs Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab, openslide

I am trying to install openslide-python on google datalabs Jupyter notebook using: 
        !apt-get install python-openslide

It runs, until it prints out:

```
   Need to get 13.0 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 44.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I type in Y in the next cell, and hit run. It says running... but nothing seems to happen.
How do it get to install python-openslide here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please can you try the following which includes the `-y` option?

```
!apt-get install -y python-openslide
```

Here is the definition of the `-y` option for `apt-get` from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/apt-get.8.html.

> ```
>    -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>        Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
>        run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
>        changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
>        package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
>        abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
> ```

Comment: Hi Ramkumar, I'm glad it worked! At your earliest convenience, please mark this answer as accepted.